# iPhone SDK: How To Return NSString From Custom Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, null, return

I have a custom class below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NamesFix : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fixedName;

- (NSString *)fixName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "NamesFix.h"

@implementation NamesFix

@synthesize fixedName;

- (NSString *)fixName:(NSString *)name
{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"Foo"])
    {
        self.fixedName = @"Bar";
    }
    else
    {
        self.fixedName = @"";
    }
    return self.fixedName;
}
```

When I access my custom class via:

```
NamesFix *namesFix = [NamesFix alloc] init];
NSString *someString = @"Foo";

[namesFix fixName:someString];

NSLog(@"fixedName: %@", namesFix.fixedName];
```

fixedName returns `null`. Where did I got it wrong?

Comment: Usually you want to declare a `NSString` property as `copy`.

Comment: I'll just use `copy` instead of `assign` is that it?

Comment: Yes - that is what is recommended

Comment: Your mistake is that you are using assign for objective c object. This has to be retained either using copy or strong. You use assign and assign just assigns the property to the variable which is released instantly after assignment. So, if you use strong, copy, retain, this should work fine.

Comment: namesFix.fixedName is accessing the property. This is fine. What you didn't do is assign the value to the property instead of it remaining an IVAR. You should either a) in the method instructions, set self.fixedName to @"Bar" or b) when calling that method outside of that object, assign a pointer to grab the result of the method (because right now, you have a return value that returns what you want but doesn't return it to anything

Comment: I updated my question above and it still returns null. How come?

Comment: Have you initialized the IVAR fixedname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your property copy which is the recommended memory management attribute for strings
(you could use retain instead, but copy protects you from others passing in the mutable
subclass NSMutableString and have it changed without you noticing) :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fixedName;
```

and in your implementation, USE the setter method that this property provides:

```
self.fixedName = ...
```

Instead of

```
fixedName = ...
```

**edit**

and also use `return self.fixedString` as a matter of habit.